# Which option in my tsconfig.json is causing error?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning typescript.

```
interface FooOptions {
  x: string;
  y: string;
}

function getFoo(opt: FooOptions) {
  return opt.x + opt.y;
}

export {getFoo, FooOptions};
```

Running `node_modules/.bin/tsc` gives the following error:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/tsc
t.ts(6,22): error TS4078: Parameter 'opt' of exported function has or is using private name 'FooOptions'.
```

But `node_modules/.bin/tsc t.ts` runs successfully.

According to [the document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> By invoking tsc with no input files, in which case the compiler
>   searches for the tsconfig.json file starting in the current directory
>   and continuing up the parent directory chain.

Which option in my tsconfig.json is causing the error?  And what does the error mean?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the interface as well:

```
export interface FooOptions {
    x: string;
    y: string;
}
```

Comment: That works! I'm wondering what's the difference between `export interface FooOptions` and `export {getFoo, FooOptions};` And why does `node_modules/.bin/tsc t.ts` run successfully?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are not getting this error when you run `tsc`. When I tried to reproduce the issue, the error was being thrown